# UIWebView The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have met a trouble ,when i load an url by UIWebView an alert show .I get this error message:"error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.hnagroup.net” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x9187ae0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.hnagroup.net/, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.hnagroup.net/, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.hnagroup.net” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0x9187b30 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.hnagroup.net” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=}"

I have seen this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But this  can't fix my problem

Comment: my test webSite is [link](https://web.hnair.net)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20789128/730807 it might help