# UIWebView not loading https link

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, https, uiwebview

I am trying to load one secure HTTP url into UIWebView, but it throws me an "untrusted certificate error" i.e error -1202. NSURLDomainError.

I searched on stackoverflow and found out this solution and implemented the same:
[UIWebView to view self signed websites (No private api, not NSURLConnection) - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i)

As per this solution after receiving a callback to : 
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;

We again load the secure http url to webview, and as we have already done the authentication pass, 
it loads the data.Also, the credential the server uses are my personal crendetials, so i am mentioning the NSURL
NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username"
                                                                  password:@"password"
persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

But my problem here is, it just goes into some kind of loop, and i am not able to get any of the callback of UIWebView. Any solution or any idea what the problem will be?

Comment: Have you implemented the UIWebView's protocol ?

Comment: Yes @VaibhavGautam .. got through the problem. Seems it was network related issue, as i did not make any modifications than above mentioned implementation.