# Is this specialized use of NSURLConnection to handle self signed certs convertible to NSURLSession?

Tags: swift, ssl, nsurlconnection, deprecated, self-signed

I have a self signed certificate in the VM I use to test my service.  Using answers found in [UIWebView to view self signed websites (No private api, not NSURLConnection) - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/) I was able to write functioning swift 2.0 code.  Xcode 7 tells me that `NSURLConnection` is deprecated and I should use `NSURLSession` instead.  None of my attempts to migrate this code succeeded, and none of the usual conversion scenarios described in other answers seem to apply.

If I create a new `NSURLSession` in order to handle the authentication challenge with my delegate methods, the other loads still happen on the `sharedSession`, and therefore fail.

```
var authRequest : NSURLRequest? = nil
var authenticated = false
var trustedDomains = [:] // set up as necessary

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if !authenticated {
        authRequest = request
        let urlConnection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)!
        urlConnection.start()
        return false
    }
    else if isWebContent(request.URL!) { // write your method for this
        return true
    }
    return processData(request) // write your method for this
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) {
    if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
        let challengeHost = challenge.protectionSpace.host
        if let _ = trustedDomains[challengeHost] {
            challenge.sender!.useCredential(NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!), forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)
        }
    }
    challenge.sender!.continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
    authenticated = true
    connection.cancel()
    webview!.loadRequest(authRequest!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to suppress the deprecation warning by adding this line before the first method.  I would prefer a solution that replaces NSURLConnection but in the absence of that, this will have to do.

```
// hide NSURLConnection deprecation
@available(iOS, deprecated=9.0)
```