# Call iOS webview HTTPS (self-signed certificate)

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, https

I want to call HTTPS url (self-signed certificate) in my iOS App. it works on the mobile browser but not in the App Webview.

Is there a solution for Xcode 7 and Swift 2.2?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let url = NSURL(string: "https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:xxxx")

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        Webview.loadRequest(request)
    }
```

Comment: plz post some error log.

Comment: [41964:1001742] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Comment: See the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i

Answer (score 7):

You have to install the *Self Signed Certificate* or *CA* on the device in order for the device to trust it
then only device trusts the SSL connection.

In the case of installing *self signed certificate* make sure *domain name* of the *URL* is same as *Common name* of certificate.

If there is no domain name then IP address is fine.

**Certificate installation:**

You can just host it on the web server and try to access it from safari then iOS will prompt for the certificate installation in the iOS Device

**Certificate Creation:**

Here is the way to create self signed certificate so that you can fill all the details and host in web server.

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 1001 -nodes
```

(Pay attention while entering the value for Common Name)

Answer (score -1):

try to add below code in your plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```