# SSL error, NSURLRequest & invalid certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, asihttprequest

I have a self signed certificate I'm using for development. I'm trying to request a webpage in my app.

Here's the code:

```
 NSURL* myUrl  = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

    [self.webView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

..when the request goes through, my error method gets hit:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}
```

and writes this to the logger:

```
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be....
```

What can I do to "connect anyway", so that I can test this in development?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6792213/730701).

Answer (score 1):

Using the below two methods we can allow self signed certificates

```
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace;

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

To find out how to achieve it using these methods visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20789128/730807)