# in UiWebView - NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -108)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, ipad, uiwebview

When I open a link in UIWebView and click on facebook icon of content of that URL it gives the following error

```
2014-01-09 13:15:14.412 AppName[2067:5407] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-108)
2014-01-09 13:15:14.412 AppName[2067:5407] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-108)
2014-01-09 13:15:15.063 AppName[2067:5407] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-108)
2014-01-09 13:15:15.064 AppName[2067:5407] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -108)
```

I also search this error in google But no result found for **-108**. results found for **98***

and this same link same process works in safari and also in other app UIWebView.
but I take new project for second app and put this link in UIWebView, It gives error.

Please Help and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tested this on multiple devices? Is it happening in your simulator too?

Comment: yes I test it in two devices and simulator also. but don't work in any device or simulator.'

Comment: Can you post some code related to loading the link in WebView? or sample project?

Answer (score 10):

If you put this anywhere in your code the app will bypass certificate validation:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)

+(BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is a private API and may result in rejection during app store review.

Comment: Only use this for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook have **`https`** protocol in URL.

Loading a **`https`** url in `UIWebview` in different from loading the normal **`https`** url.

And to load **`https`** URL please have a look at [loading-https-url-in-uiwebview](http://techmobistore.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/loading-https-url-in-uiwebview/) and this [SO Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365774/call-https-url-in-uiwebview/20789128#20789128) and  [SO Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164/uiwebview-to-view-self-signed-websites-no-private-api-not-nsurlconnection-i) here.

It may help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are trying to find this:

```
BOOL _Authenticated;
NSURLRequest *_FailedRequest;
#pragma UIWebViewDelegate

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    BOOL result = _Authenticated;
    if (!_Authenticated) {
        _FailedRequest = request;
        NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [urlConnection start];
    }
    return result;
}

#pragma NSURLConnectionDelegate

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        NSURL* baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"];
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:baseURL.host]) {
            NSLog(@"trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else
            NSLog(@"Not trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)pResponse {
    _Authenticated = YES;
    [connection cancel];
    [webvw loadRequest:_FailedRequest];
}
```