# Bypass kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error for self-signed certificates on iOS 7

Tags: ios7, https, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

I am trying to load a HTTPS web page, which has a self-signed certificate, in to an UIWebView. Using tips like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365774/call-https-url-in-uiwebview), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447318/switching-from-http-to-https-invalid-certificate), it works under iOS 6. The same does not work in iOS 7.

As per the linked-to Stack Overflow questions, I'm also using an NSURLConnection to first try and get past the self-signed certificate -- this all before even trying to load the URL in the UIWebView.

When trying the same in iOS 7, I get the following error:

> 2014-02-12 16:00:08.367 WebView[24176:5307] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
>
> 2014-02-12 16:00:08.370 WebView[24176:70b] An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

Is there a work-around to get this to work in iOS 7? At the moment I'm using the [first example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365774/call-https-url-in-uiwebview).

Comment: Try to use this implementing the UIWebViewDelegate methods: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15074358/1694129

Comment: basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573164 which now also has a solution written in swift

Answer (score 17):

Please follow the link:

[in UiWebView - NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -108)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014617/in-uiwebview-nsurlconnection-cfurlconnection-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrord/24308288#24308288)

```c
BOOL _Authenticated;
NSURLRequest *_FailedRequest;
#pragma UIWebViewDelegate

-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    BOOL result = _Authenticated;
    if (!_Authenticated) {
        _FailedRequest = request;
        NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [urlConnection start];
    }
    return result;
}

#pragma NSURLConnectionDelegate

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        NSURL* baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"];
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:baseURL.host]) {
            NSLog(@"trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else
            NSLog(@"Not trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)pResponse {
    _Authenticated = YES;
    [connection cancel];
    [webvw loadRequest:_FailedRequest];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in your class:

```c
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        NSURL* baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL"];

        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.host isEqualToString:baseURL.host])
        {
            SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;

            NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:trust];
            [challenge.sender useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Not trusting connection to host %@", challenge.protectionSpace.host);
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```