# App Transport Security ios 9 and instagram api

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api

I have a problem with instagram API and iOS 9.
My app works correctly on iOS 8, but not on iOS 9.
I receive this error when I try to authorize a user in instagram

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

I tried a lot of variants, for example from this question [App Transport Security breaks Web View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305061/app-transport-security-breaks-web-view)

Please help me!

Comment: Provide details about what you actually tried. This issue has been covered many times already.

Comment: are you using http url loads or HTTPS urls?

Comment: I use UIWebView and try to load request: [_webView loadRequest:req] with URL: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/.... (HTTPS url)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is for the ATS, if you use xcode 7 it will embeeded with ATS feature, try to build with not the version 7 like 6.1 xcode, and you can run it on ios9 devices and the calls to http will work.

Comment: Bad advice, it should not be the accepted answer. Xcode 6.1 is not available anymore for most of us now.

Answer (score 3):

[Poisondmind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32895670/1607485) is almost correct. But there are several additions to `Info.plist` that are required for instagram images to load.

Once again the description of all keys can be found in [ATS technotes.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)
Make sure you're using `https:` URLs.

Also note the useful debugging command:
 `/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose YOUR_URL`

Below is the configuration that lets my app download images from instagram:

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks a lot @nkukushkin <3

Answer (score 1):

Apple did this for important security reasons and eventually it will be necessary to enabled Transport Security in app updates. Using an older version disables it entirely. This fixed it for me on Xcode7:

In your `Info.plist` file, add `instagram.com` and subdomains as an exception to ATS rules like so:

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>instagram.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

More info about what this is doing is documented in Apple's Transport Security [technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/).