# Post Request in wkwebview using form submit does not work in some cases as no referrer headers sent out

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest, wkwebview

I am performing Post Request in **wkwebview** by submitting a form works good when I try to login some social websites as described [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253133/cant-set-headers-on-my-wkwebview-post-request) question's answer, except Facebook mobile site.
Facebook gives me the error message `do no enter your password on sites not located at facebook.com`
which maeans facebook is able to detect referrer, may be through the headers sent out.
m.facebook.com needs header value of referrer to be m.facebook.com only
and I am not abe to set the headers in my post call
I tried to modify my request in **decidePolicyForNavigationAction**

```
    func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    let urlString = navigationAction.request.URL!
    if(urlString.absoluteString.rangeOfString("https://m.facebook.com/login/?email") != nil){    // which decides it is a post req and is for facebook

        let req =  navigationAction.request;

        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.loadRequest(req);
              decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Cancel)        
    }else{
             decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow)
    }
}
```

then I got to know that this request is not mutable ,so cannot be modified , so I tried it with the mutable copy of it

```
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: navigationAction.request.URL!) 
      and this                 
        let req =  navigationAction.request.mutableCopy();
      instead of 
        let req =  navigationAction.request;
```

but none of them worked.
I asked the same in the comments of the above question (whose link I provided), but no response, is there any work around for this?

If anyone could help me in this, I'll be more then Happy
Thanks in advance :)